# How to extract private key for Ethereum Ledger Account using Recovery Phrase BIP39 tool?

Tags: erc-20, private-key, bip39

Can someone please tell me how to find my public key address in a "sea" of Derived Addresses when using the BIP39 (44 for Ethereum) tool?

I've isolated a laptop with this loaded in a browser, put in my Ledger 24 word recovery phrase, selected coin "Ethereum" which set to m/44'/60'/0'/0.

I'm then presented with 20 derived addresses at a time, none of which are display my public key that I'm looking for.

Is there anything I can do to better isolate my search results so I can find the address I'm looking for?

My goal is to recover ERC20 THETA that is locked on my Ledger Ethereum wallet.  If I can get the private key, I can enter this into THETA's site and recover the transferred THETA & TFuel as it was taken in a snapshot long since passed.

MANY THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 1):

Use iancolman 44'/0'/0'/0 i hope you can find you Xpub key here if you can't find it i will answer again with more info

Comment: This was flagged as not an answer. He is already using that tool and you should explain your answer more: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer